# render django dictionary with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

how can i populate the `select tag` or  `ul and li tag` with ajax request sent to django and it returns json  ( may also be from a model ). i do not want to use another template for populating these.

example :

if the return is `data` from ajax request

how can i do this :

```
      <select id = 'carid'>
            {% for car in cars %}
                     <option value="{{ car.name }}">{{ car.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

but i do not want to return html from django or load another html only for this tag.

This is my Response method

```
 def car_view(request)

    car_obj = cars.objects.get(name = car)

    allmodels = CarModel.objects.filter(car = car_obj)

    data = serializers.serialize("json", allmodels)

    return HttpResponse(data)
```

this is how `data` looks like

```
[{"pk": 3, "model": "alongjs.carmodel", "fields": {"car": 2, "name": "city-unlimited"}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "alongjs.carmodel", "fields": {"car": 2, "name": "hill-to-city"}}]`
```

Comment: how are you sending the ajax request? jQuery.ajax()? post that code and an example of the JSON it returns

Comment: what does 'data' look like?

Comment: I have added how data looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending an `ajax` request with [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (looks like you are judging from previous questions) - you can add some JavaScript inside the success callback function to iterate over the `JSON` response and populate your `select` options.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: ...,
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      $('#carid')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr('value', this['fields']['name'])
        .text(this['fields']['name'])); 
    });
  }
});
```

You can see a contrived fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3rZ7x/).

You can probably improve your JSON though - as all you need is the car name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it greatly helped, but when ever there a post again , the data is getting appended. I see that you have added `.append`. what should i do to not to have appending results all the time.

Comment: You could use jQuery.html('') to remove all the existing select options and then append all the new ones included in the JSON response - like this http://jsfiddle.net/pRzL5/

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot , just what i needed. if it's not much of a trouble , can you point out to me some resources where i can learn more on this json parsing. Once Again thanks