# Parsing JSON(query set) from django view

Tags: ajax, json, django

How do i parse this JSON string:

```
[
    {"pk": 3,
     "model": "alongjs.carmodel",
     "fields":
          {"car": 2, "name": "city-unlimited"}},


    {"pk": 4,
     "model": "alongjs.carmodel",
     "fields":
         {"car": 2, "name": "hill-to-city"}

    }
]
```

I only want to get `fields['name']`. this is being returned from Django view. I have serialised the query set to `json`. This is being retuned in ajax response.

Comment: I explained how you can do this in the question you asked earlier today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571135/render-django-dictionary-with-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you've got a variable called `response` containing the content of the AJAX response, you want something like this:

```
loaded_data = json.loads(response)
for record in loaded_data:
    print record["fields"]["name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the return value of django view is a list then

```
## Lets say variable data contains your query response
    data = [
    {"pk": 3,
     "model": "alongjs.carmodel",
     "fields":
          {"car": 2, "name": "city-unlimited"}},


    {"pk": 4,
     "model": "alongjs.carmodel",
     "fields":
         {"car": 2, "name": "hill-to-city"}}
]
for x in data:
    print x['fields']['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

While this question has been brilliantly been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571135/render-django-dictionary-with-ajax) . I have found another way.

```
  var to_parse = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  var temp = '';

  for (var i in to_parse)
       {
        temp += "<option>" + to_parse[i].fields.name + "</option>";
   }

 alert(temp)
```

I have Used [jQuery.parseJSON](https://gist.github.com/zuch/3720842).